# MySql Connection Pool leaked after ThreadAbortedException

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ado.net, datareader

**I updated the code in order to simplify it**

I’ve encountered a strange issue that never happened before on this code (run perfectly for 2 years).

I’m running MVC application over multiple IISs, and using MySQL over C# code.

Querying table X receives response from a different table in the same schema.

The issue happens sporadically on some IIS (once a 1-4 days) and solved by 3 iisreset.

Here is the code I’m using (**updated**):

```
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sql;

            IDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new MoranbernateQueryException(sql, ex);
            }

            using (reader)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sql, GetTableFromReader(reader));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetTableFromReader(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        var rows = schema?.Rows;
        if (rows != null && schema.Columns.Count > 11)
        {
            return rows[0][10].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The result of this code is an sql query to table A but the table (and data) from the reader schema is B. Both tables resides in the same DB and Schema.

Has anyone else encountered this type of problem? I’d like to hear any theory or suggestion for investigation.

Comment: command is an instance of MySqlConnection, How do you manage to compile this code?

Comment: @GSerg - reader will be disposed after the using block finishes.  But it would be worth seeing the method declaration that this lives within and how it is called.

Comment: I work with @Tom and i want to update on the matter, we found that we had a long process running due to some feature(removed), yet iis had thrown `ThreadAbortedException` thus no try catch while reading data from `MySql`, The consicuence was that our connection pool was not synced and we got connection leakage.
Now we are trying to understand if this is a MySql driver problem or something else. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how do you access reader even it out of scope, there is may problem with flow of your code. use below code i think this have to work.

```
using(var command = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 command.CommandText = sql;

 try
  {
    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

      while (reader.Read())
            {
                var t = new T();
                var i = 0;

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        property.SetValue(t, reader.GetValue(i++));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        HandleSetValueException<T>(sql, parameters, reader, connection, ex);
                    }
                }
                yield return t;
            }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw new MoranbernateQueryException(sql, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it's a known issue that was fixed by MySql team, after updating the driver all is well for now
[image]